# please help me to Call a printing Method

Tags: java, class, methods, call

I have created a method to print my files, however it only passes the true value instead of my actual values from the **.dat** file. Will you take a look at my method and tell what i'm doing wrong, please? Thank you so much.

calls the printing method:

```
System.out.println(printColumnHeaders(vehicles[x], false, false));
```

My Printing method:

```
private  static  boolean  printColumnHeaders(Vehicle vehicle,boolean isFirst,boolean printFull ) {

    if(isFirst && printFull) {
         System.out.println(vehicle.printFullHeadings());
         isFirst = true;
         printFull = true;
     }
     else  if(isFirst){
         System.out.println(vehicle.printSummaryHeadings());
         isFirst = true;
     }
    return false; 
    }
```

this method suppose to check If isFirst boolean value is true and printFull boolean value is true
then, Call the vehicle’s printFullHeadings method
next, Else if isFirst boolean value is true
last, Call the vehicle’s printSummaryHeadings method

Comment: Since you passing in false for isFrirst and printFull your method drops through the returns false to System.out.println.  So that all that is printed.

Comment: Your arguements isFirst and printFull are both false. So your method just returns false.

Comment: in printColumnHeaders you havent used vehicle varibale instead have used vehicles[x] is it a issue?

Comment: where is the place you read .dat file value ?

Comment: @Sura at my main method, and it reads it fine... do you see any errors in my code at all?

Comment: can you explain me what is you really expect from printColumnHeaders method.

Comment: @Sura here is my expectation: "printColumnHeaders :"
i. If isFirst boolean value is frue and printFull boolean value is true
1. Call the vehicle’s printFullHeadings method
ii. Else if isFirst boolean value is true
1. Call the vehicle’s printSummaryHeadings method

Comment: Can you just show printFullHeadings  and printSummaryHeadings methods implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how I fixed it:

```
private static void displayVehicleData(String displayType) {
    boolean isFirst = true;

    for(int x = 0; x < vehicles.length; x++){

        switch(displayType) {

            case "Vehicles" : // List All Vehicles
                isFirst = printColumnHeaders(vehicles[x], false, isFirst);
                    System.out.println(vehicles[x].printSummaryOutput());

                break;
            case "Cars": // List All Cars
                    if(vehicles[x].getVehicleType().equals("American Car") || 
                        vehicles[x].getVehicleType().equals("Foreign Car")) {
                        isFirst = printColumnHeaders(vehicles[x], false, isFirst);
                        System.out.println(vehicles[x].printSummaryOutput());
                    }
```

Printing method:

```
private  static  boolean  printColumnHeaders(Vehicle vehicle, boolean printFull, boolean isFirst) {

                if(isFirst && printFull){
                    System.out.println(vehicle.printFullHeadings());
                }                                       
                else if (isFirst){
                    System.out.println(vehicle.printSummaryHeadings());
                }

            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, since you are passing in false, false your method isn't printing.  But you also seem to have a logic problem since your static method always returns a boolean which your are passing into System.out.println.   You might try something like:

`if ( printColumnHeaders(System.out, vehicles[x], false, false) == false)
 
  ... handle print error`

Your print method is then:

`private  static  boolean  printColumnHeaders(java.io.PrintStream writer, Vehicle vehicle,boolean isFirst,boolean printFull ) {`

```
if(isFirst && printFull) {
     writer.println(vehicle.printFullHeadings());
     isFirst = true;
     printFull = true;
 }
 else  if(isFirst){
     writer.println(vehicle.printSummaryHeadings());
     isFirst = true;
 }
return false; 
}
```

This allows your method to output to more than just standard out.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(printColumnHeaders(vehicles[x], false, false));
```

You're passing false, false into the printColumnHeaders method which just causes it to terminate and return false, which gets printed by the call to System.out.println().

If you call a method as an argument to println() it will print the return value of that method, not whatever you expected to be printed inside that method.